# Why does RobotParser block this result?

Tags: python, web-crawler, robots.txt

I have been using Python's robotparser for a while now and it's working fine. This morning I ran across a website with a very permissive looking robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

However, for some reason, the parser thinks all URLs are blocked.

```
import robotparser
rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser("http://newenglandreptileshop.com/robots.txt")
rp.read()
# Try any URL
rp.can_fetch("*", "http://www.newenglandreptileshop.com")

False
```

My assumption is that crawling all paths is permissible unless denied. I used another robots.txt parser to check my assumption and it agreed that I should be able to access most URLs on this server. And Google has them indexed too.

Seems like a bug in the Python library. What's going on?

Comment: I don’t know RobotParser, just an idea: same problem if you use the same host? You use `newenglandreptileshop.com` (without `www`), and then `www.newenglandreptileshop.com` (with `www`).

Comment: Good eye. Unfortunately that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Robot Exclusion Standard found at https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard there is no such thing as an Allow record.  To allow access you must add an empty Disallow record.  Try hosting the robots.txt on a domain you control and remove the explicit allow record and seeing if RobotParser returns True for can_fetch.

Comment: Thanks, but that still don't answer to me why any path outside the one disallowed would be disallowed (I don't care about the /wp-admin/ path).